# Active scene camera reverting to Amature?

Tags: rendering, camera

When I select the active camera in the scene everything looks ok, but when I go to render the image the camera is at a weird location (the origin?) looking up at my character.

I've set the camera in the Scene properties panel, but when I hit F12 the Camera changes to'Armature' weirdly, which is obviously not even a camera.

I tried deleting all the cameras in the file and recreating but no luck.

Anyone know what is going here??

Comment: You might want to spice up your question with some screenshots, namely Object View, Outliner and Render result. You can also share files via [https://blend-exchange.com/](https://blend-exchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

OK I solved this, when scrubbing through the timeline I noticed the scene camera also switched to 'Amature'. At the bottom of the timeline it was showing a little camera icon with Amature next to it.

This is a marker which is used to set the active camera during rendering and animation. Select the icon and then go to *Marker > Delete Marker* and it will get rid of it.